# Exit editor without exiting psql

Tags: psql, pager

When I run `\dt` (and other commands of `psql` like `\l`) this thing appears. What is this? Is this an editor?

Most importantly, when I click `Ctrl+Z`, I get thrown out of `psql` completely. **How do I exit it without exiting `psql`?**

[image]

I am totally new to Ubuntu, so sorry if its a dumb question. Thanks for your time on advance!

Comment: That's your pager, usually you can exit the pager using `q`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to come from Windows.

The pager that gets invoked whenever a query result does not fit on your screen is something similar to Windows' `more`, so you exit it by typing <kbd>q</kbd>.

If you don't want a pager at all, set the environment variable `PAGER` to an empty string:

```sh
PAGER='' psql
```

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will not send an End-of-file on Linux, it will suspend the current foreground process, which continues to lurk in the background. You can rescue it from there with the command `fg`.